# Populating a PATH env variable using programmatic command substitution $() leads to a literal giant string, rather than tokenized paths

Tags: linux, bash, shell, path, environment-variables

I'm creating a `PATH` environment variable that begins with `/foo` and ends with `/bar`; and in between I "sandwich" in a collection of related `bin` paths that I programmatically concatenate together, as shown:

```sh
export PATH=/foo:$(ls -1d /path/to/*/bin | xargs | sed -e 's/ /:/'g):/bar
```

The issue I'm having is that the in-between collection of paths are interpreted as one giant string, rather than as tokenized paths separated by a colon (":").

I tried variations in a attempt to get a tokenized result, such as:

```
export PATH=/foo:$(echo $(ls -1d /path/to/*/bin | xargs | sed -e 's/ /:/'g)):/bar
```

but no luck. I also tried variants that include an `eval(1)`, and so on. I suppose I can next try using `find(1)` and friends.

What does work is **pasting in the literal long string**, but that's a bummer because it's not programmatic.

Incidentally, this issue isn't specific to `PATH` because substituting in `export BLAH=...` results in the same issue.

Any ideas for modifying the above so that the result is tokenized? You can try this yourself by creating, say, `user$ mkdir -p /tmp/{1,2,3,4}/bin` and playing around.

Whatever the solution is, it's just not coming to me today. =:)

Comment: The `PATH` variable isn't explicitly tokenized; it's just a plain string that happens to contain paths separated by colons. What is the actual string value you get as a result of this? BTW, one weird thing I see is that you use `echo $(something)`, which is almost always a mistake -- the `echo` and the `$( )` basically cancel each other, except that there's an opportunity for the shell to do weird things if the string contains certain characters. Speaking of which, have you changed `IFS`? If you have, that could be causing trouble.

Comment: How about `export PATH="/foo:$(printf %s: /path/to/*/bin)/bar"`?

Comment: Hi @LéaGris @GordonDavisson  Thanks to both of you. Let me try the `printf` now. BRB. :)

Comment: @LéaGris Yes, that worked. How delightful! `\o/` Why don't you pose that as an answer and I will `accept` and `upvote` it. Thank you.

Comment: @NYCeyes I let you write your own answer based on the `printf` trick and explain how it works. You will learn much by redacting your own answer and you will earn some badge here ^^

Comment: @LéaGris Thank you. Okay, over the weekend I will write and explain for the benefit others and myself, but I will feel guilty taking the credit. Have a good night or day wherever you are.

Comment: @LéaGris had excellent comment. To create zero-fork alternative (and no extra vars touched) one could do (in bash): `printf -v PATH %s: /path/to/*/bin; PATH=/foo:${PATH}/bar` (In this case $PATH would have been good as /bar does not start with [a-z0-9_] but as an example (someone copies this elsewhere modified) thos {}s are better to have there).

Comment: @TomiOllila Another one: `_arr=(/foo /path/to/*/bin /bar); _OIFS="$IFS"; IFS=:; printf -v PATH %s "${_arr[*]}"; IFS="$_OIFS"; unset _arr _OIFS; export PATH`